# Portrait within Landscape

Tags: iphone, ios4, interface-builder

I am using the interface builder in Xcode 4.  I have created a 480(w)x320(h) image to use in landscape mode for my app.  WIthin IB I set the view's orientation to "landscape".  I place my image on the view.  I have set the "supported device orientation" to landscape letf/right.  I have changed the info.plist to support landscape orientations.

Here's the weird part: When I run the app, the simulator does rotate/start in landscape, however, my image has somehow rotated 90 degrees as well so it appears cropped and and only takes up about 1/3 of the screen.

So to simplify the explanation, the image always appears in the opposite rotation of the view.  I have tried removiong the .png file and re-adding and performing a "clean" with no luck.  ANy advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shoukd to modify your shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation metho in all your viewControllers, that should be in landscape:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {  
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {  
        return YES;  
    } 
}
```